# Not reaching the end of the function

Tags: node.js, callback, mongoose

I have a JS function which adds a UserArticle to the DB (using mongoose and NodeJS). The problem is that it doesn't reach the end.

I mean, I have tried to determine at which place the majority of time reaches and is before the `Provider.findOne` or, before `User.find`.

```
var insertUserArticleToAllSubscribers = function (base_ua, providerId) {
    var Provider = mongoose.model('Provider');
    var User = mongoose.model('User');
    var UserArticle = mongoose.model('UserArticle');
    Provider.findOne({"twitter_id": providerId}, function (err, provider) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            return;
        }
        if (provider) {
            User.find({"subscribed": provider._id}, function (err, users) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log (err);
                    return;
                }
                if (users) {
                    for (i in users) {
                        var ua = new UserArticle ({"user": users[i], "article":base_ua.article, "place":base_ua.place, "read":0, "starred":0});
                        ua.save(function (err) {
                            if (err) console.log(err);
                            logAddedArticle(ua._id, users[i]);
                            console.log("ArticleAdded!: " + ua._id);            

                        });

                    }
                } else {
                    console.log("No users");
                }
            })
        }
    })
}
```

I don't understand why it doesn't reach the end of the function without throwing any error. Is there a bug in this piece of code?

Well, in fact, it sometimes reaches the end of the function but almost always it doesn't.

Thank you

Comment: What exactly do you mean when you say the end of the function? The function in findOne and find are asynchronous, so they won't run until after insertUserArticleToAllSubscribers has returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that Provider.findOne() is actually invoking the callback (hopefully a safe assumption), then you probably need an `else` on the first `if( provider )` call.

Right now you have this logical structure:

```
function (...) {
    Provider.findOne(..., function (...) {
        if (err) { ... }
        if (provider) {
            User.find(..., function(...) {
                if (err) { ... }
                if (users) { ... } 
                else { ... }
            })
        }
    })
```

You will probably get a result if you change it to this:

```
function (...) {
    Provider.findOne(..., function (...) {
        if (err) { ... }
        else if (provider) {                   // MAKE THIS AN ELSE IF
            User.find(..., function(...) {
                if (err) { ... }
                else if (users) { ... }        // MAKE THIS AN ELSE IF!
                else { ... }
            })
        }
        else {                                 // ADD THIS ELSE!
            console.log('findOne() found nuttin :(');
        }
    })
```